# How can I get my inner div to center vertically and horizontally

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="footercenter">

    <div id="footer_copyright">abc</div><div id="footer_message">def</div>

</div>
```

The inner two divs appear next to each other but at the top of the footercenter. Is there a way that I can make these appear centered vertically?

Hope for some help.

Mandy J

Answer (score 0):

Check out...

http://www.infinitywebdesign.com/research/cssverticalcentereddiv.htm

View the page source and CSS